# Calculating the slope of each row in a large data set using R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, linear-regression

I have a large `data set` of the following `format`:
First column is `type`, and the `subsequent columns` are different times that `'type'` happens. I want to calculate the slope of each `row (~7000 rows)` for `subset T0-T2` and then `t0-t2` and output that information, then get the average of the slopes for each row. For example, get the slope of subset T0-T2 and of t0-t2 for type1 then get an average of the two values for row type1. 
Some rows have missing data entirely, while some are missing either a single or two values.

```
Type    T0   T1   T2   t0   t1   t2  
type1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.3  0.2  0.1 
type2  1.4  2.5  3.4  1.5  0.5  3.4
type3  0.4  8.1  8.1       2.2
type4        
...
```

I am a beginner in `R`, and so it has been challenging trying to do this, as much as in my head it seems simple. I am getting errors in the missing values (NA) and I will appreciate any ideas, or directions to a similar question on this site. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'slope of each row'? 
As ~7000 rows is not really big, you can use the `apply` function family in R. Simply type in `?apply`. If your `data.frame` is `x`, you want something like `apply(x[,-1], 1, mean, na.rm=T)`. This means apply the `mean` function with extra argument `na.rm=TRUE` to every row (`1`) of `x` without the first column `Type` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you might want to write a function that can calculate the slope for three consecutive values, like this:

```
slope  <-  function(x){
    if(all(is.na(x)))
        # if x is all missing, then lm will throw an error that we want to avoid
        return(NA)
    else
        return(coef(lm(I(1:3)~x))[2])
}
```

Then you can use the `apply()` function to calculate the slope for each row (MARGIN = 1) like so:

```
df <- read.csv(text = 
"Type,T0,T1,T2,t0,t1,t2
type1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1 
type2,1.4,2.5,3.4,1.5,0.5,3.4
type3,0.4,8.1,8.1,,2.2,")


df$slope1  <-  
    apply(df[,c('T0','T1','T2')],
          1,
          slope)

df$slope2  <-  
    apply(df[,c('t0','t1','t2')],
          1,
          slope)
```

then calculate the average slope:

```
df$average.slope  <-  (df$slope1 + df$slope2)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the slopes for each row doing something like:

```
#dat <- read.table(text="Type    T0   T1   T2   t0   t1   t2  
#type1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.3  0.2  0.1 
#type2  1.4  2.5  3.4  1.5  0.5  3.4
#type3  0.4  8.1  8.1   NA  2.2   NA",header=TRUE)

tapply(
  dat[c("T0","T1","T2")],
  dat["Type"],
  FUN=function(x) 
    coef(lm(unlist(x) ~ seq_along(x)))[-1]
)

#Type
#type1 type2 type3 
# 0.10  1.00  3.85
```